# MySQL Import text file with one word per line

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a text file with one word per line. I haven't been able to get it to import into mysql table with a field called name.

What options do I need to use for importing?

My text file is like:

```
random
name
one
two
three
```

Comment: search and replace?, adding a coma after each end of line and adding at the beginning `insert into XXX values .....` could work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE my_table(name)
```

**EDIT**:

Seems like you cannot specify both columns list (`(name)` in this case) and `FIELDS`/`LINES` clauses at the same time - really weird.

Comment: I tried to use these with phpmyadmin, but I get the error: Invalid parameter for CSV import: Fields escaped by

Comment: Have you tried to drop this part (`ESCAPED BY '\\'`)? You have no escapes anyway.

Comment: Yeah, leaving it blank phpmyadmin still gives me the same error.

Comment: Try just `LOAD DATA INFILE '\path\to\data.txt' INTO TABLE my_table(name)`

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way would be to use [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html)

with the parameter `--lines-terminated-by="\n"`